# wordpress wp_mail dynamic attachments

Tags: php, wordpress, dynamic

i am able to send an e-mail using the wp_mail function. Now I want to send an attachment with it, which link is dynamically. Is this possible with the function?

```
$pdflink = 'http://xxxyyy.com'.$_POST['anhang'];
$attachments = array($pdflink);

wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $attachments );
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This is wp_mail function. Before give $attachments as parameter check it is array() or not then used it.

```
wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments );
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Please explain a little more. Thank you for the answer!

Comment: please refer this link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/. I think in your code $attachement declaration create error. Please make it correct.